# Connect to VPN through another VPN

Tags: networking, macos, vpn

On Mac I use a VPN to connect to the office network, can i make that connection see my IP as coming from a different country by first connecting to another VPN?

I'm using SurfShark as client, I can connect to a VPN in Germany for example and also connect to my work VPN in UK... I can see both of them connected and my external IP looks like it's the second one (from the UK VPN). Does it mean it's working and if anyone looks into my IP from the UK office will see the Germany IP?

If this is not working is there any way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The UK office will only see that an IP from Germany has connected to their VPN server.

However, from your credentials that you used to login to the UK VPN, they will still
be able to identify you. If they pay attention to this, they might ask why you are
in Germany instead of working.

Comment: Yeah that's totally fine, it's actually the expected outcome. I searched the internet and all articles i found say VPN thorugh VPN is not possible since you con only ever be connected with one VPN at the time only it doesn't seem to be the case for me so i just wanted to understand why those articles say it's impossible

Comment: This is untrue: VPN over VPN is possible, unless the VPN provider took some preventive action.